# Python crashing with openGl2

Tags: python, opengl, vtk, mayavi

When I try to execute a function I wrote using mayavi, python will crash and give me a message:

> Error: In
>   D:\Build\VTK-7.0.0\Rendering\OpenGL2\vtkOpenGLRenderWindow.cxx, line
>   545 vtkWin32OpenGLRenderWIndow(00002533B0F8): Gl version 2.1 with
>   gpu_shader4 extension is not supported by your graphics card (rest is
>   cut off before it terminates)

I have VTK 7.0.0, python 3.5.
What can I do to work around this and get my graphs to load?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved by updating video card drivers and changing my work environnement out of remote desktop connection that was previously being used.